# Basic network command-line shell: how can I know if some device that don't answer to pings is alive on the LAN?

Tags: linux, shell, networking

I would like to script some simple **shell program** to see if there is somebody **really connected** right now to my [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) router.
As long as these routers allow some simple/average shell, I think a good scriptable method could be **entering the router** :

```
ssh root@192.168.8.203 -p 1022

Host '192.168.8.203' is not in the trusted hosts file.
(fingerprint md5 ab:c5:94:c7:d3:56:52:1b:4b:8f:10:40:bf:1b:37:1a)
Do you want to continue connecting? (y/n) y
root@192.168.8.203's password:
==========================================================

 ____  ___    __        ______ _____         ____  _  _
 | _ \| _ \   \ \      / /  _ \_   _| __   _|___ \| || |
 || | || ||____\ \ /\ / /| |_) || |   \ \ / / __) | || |_
 ||_| ||_||_____\ V  V / |  _ < | |    \ V / / __/|__   _|
 |___/|___/      \_/\_/  |_| \_\|_|     \_/ |_____|  |_|

                       DD-WRT v24
                   http://www.dd-wrt.com

==========================================================


BusyBox v1.4.2 (2007-08-15 14:58:26 CEST) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

... then **checking the ARP** table:

```
~ # more /proc/net/arp
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.20.100   0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        br0
192.168.20.108   0x1         0x2         78:7E:61:C5:C6:7B     *        br0
192.168.20.129   0x1         0x2         F0:DB:F8:29:8F:1B     *        br0
192.168.20.110   0x1         0x0         28:5A:EB:35:CA:C9     *        br0
192.168.8.1      0x1         0x2         00:24:A5:C7:DD:BC     *        vlan1
192.168.20.111   0x1         0x2         F8:A9:D0:67:02:D4     *        br0
192.168.20.128   0x1         0x2         5C:97:F3:01:49:1C     *        br0
```

... and then, as long as **DHCP association table is not enough** (an IP address could remain there for hours after the device disconnected), trying to **ping** some of the LAN side (192.168.20.x in my example) devices:

```
~ # ping 192.168.20.111
PING 192.168.20.111 (192.168.20.111): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.20.111: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=131.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.20.111: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=265.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.20.111: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=83.5 ms
--- 192.168.20.111 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 25% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 83.5/160.2/265.5 ms
```

But, as you know, sometimes devices **don't answer to ping** requests even when they are alive (i.e: default behavior for Windows 7):

```
~ # ping 192.168.20.108
PING 192.168.20.108 (192.168.20.108): 56 data bytes
--- 192.168.20.108 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

I can not perform some nmap scan, due to it is not installed on DD-WRT.

Is there any scriptable method to know if a not-answering IP address is **alive** (the device is on) on the LAN?

Answer (score 3):

If your router has [`arping`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arping), you can use it to perform an Ethernet level ping. This is lower level than ICMP, and essentially unblockable.

```
$ arping -I eth0 192.168.28.1
ARPING 192.168.28.1 from 192.168.28.130 eth0
Unicast reply from 192.168.28.1 [00:15:60:FF:8B:40]  1.176ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.28.1 [00:15:60:FF:8B:40]  1.249ms
```

This test verifies that at a minimum the remote host's NIC is responding to ARP requests. An ARP request is when your computer asks "who has *such-and-such* IP address?" and the remote computer responds, "that's me, and my MAC address is *XYZ*." Computers do not block ARP requests because to do so would make Ethernet communication impossible.

`arping` doesn't necessarily tell you that the OS is responsive, but it does tell you the computer is powered on. Also, in contrast to ICMP pings, ARP requests are *not routable*. You can only check hosts that you are *physically connected to*.

Comment: A fine program. Saddly, it is not included on my DD-WRT firmware, and the download site ( http://freecode.com/projects/arping/ ) seems not to be offering the binary file.

Comment: Well... not exactly: DD-WRT includes `arping` but some sort of bug makes it not to show output screen :-P .

Answer (score 1):

> Even when the answer of @JohnKugelman is fine, I hope this one will be
>   more portable to simpler devices.

It seems that a simple `arp -a` command issues an attemp to locate the ARP cache devices via **network ARP request**:

```
~ # arp -a
Kelseys-iPhone (192.168.10.116) at <incomplete> on br0
danielas-iPhone (192.168.10.119) at <incomplete> on br0
iPad-de-Mery (192.168.10.114) at F0:DB:F8:29:8F:1B [ether] on br0
? (192.168.8.1) at 00:24:A5:C7:DD:BC [ether] on vlan1
sinsanguguiiPad (192.168.10.102) at <incomplete> on br0
android-a52cac45f5022d72 (192.168.10.115) at 90:B6:86:C1:5B:8F [ether] on br0
```

So, just **greping** by IP address or `incomplete` pattern should enough (example for the above output):

```
arp -a | grep "192.168.10.119" | grep "incomplet"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "Device not responding to ARP requests on network" ; fi
```

Tested working on my DD-WRT router.

(Note that I have used `incomplet` instead of `incomplete` to make it work for spanish and maybe some more languages :-) )